# Need to create a hyperlink from active cell to newly created workbook

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I am trying to create a hyperlink from an activecell to a new workbook that is created.  In wb1, employees enter data on sheet2. I have the vba to select the bottom data in column C as this will not only be the link but the name of the new wb. It then creates a new wb by copying sheet1 from wb1. It then does saveas with the new name. My trouble is that I can't seem to get the hyperlink address to work. How do I reference the address for this new wb for the hyperlink? I can't seem to make sense of the address. Thank you for the assistance.

```
Sub NewSheet()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim FName As String

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Copy Name
wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Copy

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("H5").Activate
Range("H5").PasteSpecial

'Path for saving file
Path = "C:\Excel Testing\"
'Filename
FName = ws1.Range("H5")

'Workbook created
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy

Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

'Saving workbook with new name
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb2.SaveAs filename:=Path & FName, FileFormat:=52
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
'Hyperlink cell
Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Select

wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select

'I put Path for address for placeholder for question
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=Path, SubAddress:=
    "Sheet1!", TextToDisplay:=""



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that the hyperlink is now what you expected. Since you are a new contributor, I cleaned some of your code. Hope you do not mind! Welcome.

```
Sub NewSheet2()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' Path for saving file
    Dim Path As String: Path = "C:\users\xptp183\Excel Testing\"
        
    ' Filename
    Dim FName As String
    FName = wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
       
     'Workbook created
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
    
    'Saving workbook with new name
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb2.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FName, FileFormat:=52
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ' Hyperlink cell
    wb1.Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    
    wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("d" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
    
    'I put Path for address for placeholder for question
    Dim lnkAddress As String: lnkAddress = Path & FName & ".xlsm"
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=lnkAddress, TextToDisplay:=""
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I see what my error was now that I see your solution.  I tried the =Path & FName but I didn't have the extension put in. Works wonders now.